# Haskell check for program avaliablity

Tags: windows, shell, haskell, path, portability

Is it way to check whether given string represent executable in $PATH(%path%)?
It have to be portable to Windows. Idea to just call it and see return status is not apporiate, 
as non-zero may mean program error or program not found.
Well, in code, I want following

```
possibleCompilers = ["gcc", "icc", "foo", "bar.exe"]
presentCompiler :: IO String
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That task should be doable using [`System.Directory.findExecutable`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/directory-1.1.0.2/System-Directory.html#v%3afindExecutable).

```
possibleCompiler :: IO (Maybe String)
possibleCompiler = check possibleCompilers
  where
    check [] = return Nothing
    check (c:cs) = do
       mbc <- findExecutable c
       case mbc of
         Just _ -> return mbc
         Nothing -> check cs
```

I changed the type to `IO (Maybe String)`, since maybe, none of the candidates is found.